# XML parse from the SQL table column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a XML column in the table to parse. This is a sample of the data in that column:

```
<product displaygtin="08858011802159" >

/* First Block */

<identification>
    <attributeList>
      <attribute name="gpcSegment">
        <value>Food/Beverage/Tobacco</value>
      </attribute>
    </attributeList>

/* Second Block */ 

</identification>
  <itemCertification>
    <nutrition>
      <attributeList>
        <attribute name="foodLabelVersion">
          <value>P2017</value>
        </attribute>
       </attributeList>
</nutrition>

/*Last Block*/

<certification>
      <attributeList>
        <attribute name="claimKosher">
          <value>false</value>
        </attribute>
      </attributeList>
    </certification>
  </itemCertification>

</product>
```

From the first block, I can easily extract but second and last block I am not getting any result please someone look into below query and advise how to extract from other blocks

```
SELECT [BundleID]
      ,[XML]
      ,[DisplayGTIN]
      ,b.x.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS "Division"
 FROM 
     [ItemCert_Reporting].[dbo].[Retailer_Extract] AS t1
 CROSS APPLY 
     t1.[XML].nodes('product/identification/attributeList/attribute') AS b(x)
 WHERE 
     displaygtin LIKE '%8858011802159'
     AND b.x.value('@name', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') = 'gpcSegment'
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. Please specify your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You actually only have two child nodes for product

1. identification
2. itemCertification

Your XPath expression is only valid for the first one.

As mentioned in comments, its not totally clear what your expected output is, but this might be what you are looking for

```
  create table #Product (Product XML)

insert into #Product values (
'<product displaygtin="08858011802159">
    <identification>
        <attributeList>
            <attribute name="gpcSegment">
                <value>Food/Beverage/Tobacco</value>
            </attribute>
        </attributeList>
    </identification>
    <itemCertification>
        <nutrition>
            <attributeList>
                <attribute name="foodLabelVersion">
                    <value>P2017</value>
                </attribute>
            </attributeList>
        </nutrition>
        <certification>
            <attributeList>
                <attribute name="claimKosher">
                    <value>false</value>
                </attribute>
            </attributeList>
        </certification>
    </itemCertification>
</product>')



select * from 
(select 
       pref.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(32)') as Attributes
from 
       #Product CROSS APPLY
       Product.nodes('//attributeList/attribute/value') AS Roles(pref)
)  as Result


drop table #Product
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, i tried no result i want to display " Foodlabelversion" and "claimkosher" values

Comment: Thanks Matt it worked now .... really appreciate your support